# Remote query timeout for Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm executing a stored procedure on an Azure SQL database.

The procedure is being called via Linked Server from a SQL Server Agent job on a local SQL Server instance:

```
EXEC ('EXEC azuredb.dbo.FullProcess') AT [MYAZURESERVER.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET]
```

After ca. 12 minutes of execution I get an query timeout error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "MYAZURESERVER.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET" returned message "Query timeout expired".
```

How can I disable/control remote timeout period? I tried setting the "Remote Query Timeout" to 0 in the Linked Server settings, but it doesn't seem to have an effect. Also, there seems to be no such setting on the Azure SQL Server.

Comment: Did you check the firewall rules of the Azure SQL?

Comment: The firewall rules are correctly configured. This is not the reason for this behaviour - if firewall would be an issue, then I wouldn't be able to run the stored procedure at all.

Comment: You can query from any tables in Azure sql via linked server?

Comment: Yes. The problem is the timeout error that occurs when the execution takes more than ca. 12 minutes.

Comment: Hi @saso,  Can it work now?

Comment: Hi @saso Kindly let me if you need more infomation. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
My stored procedure will execute for 12 minutes. When I set the "Remote Query Timeout" to 900 or bigger in the Linked Server settings. The "Remote Query Timeout" should be a bit larger than the actual execution time. If the values are the same, the timeout error will still be reported.
[image]
It successfully returned the result! These two time differences are the execution time of the stored procedure:
[image]

---

Hi @saso My steps are as follows. According to this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6224/create-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-azure-sql-database/), it says we need to create 2 linked servers to achieve that.

1. Create first linked server named `JOSEPHSERVER2.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET`:
   [image]
   Enter login name and password to login on Azure SQL:
   [image]
2. Create second linked server named `AZURE LINKED SERVICE`. Sceond linked server  will reference first linked server. Enter userdb name in `Catalog`.
   [image]
   Also need to enter login name and password:
   [image]
   Select Server Options and set "RPC" and "RPC Out" as true, so that we can call stored procedure via this linked server:
   [image]
3. Then I can call remote stored procedures in a local SQL Server:
   [image]

Comment: Hi Joseph. Thank you for your engagement. However, the issue here is not establishing connection from on-premise SQL Server to Azure SQL Database. This is configured and is working. Querying or executing stored procedure on Azure SQL Database using EXEC AT statement works - for most cases.

The issue is when SP is executed and the execution takes more than ca. 12 minutes, then the execution is cancelled with the "Remote Timeout Error" message. I want to modify/prolong the remote timeout value and I can't find how to do it (setting it in the Linked Server properties has no effect).

Comment: What is the effect of setting "remote query timeout" to 300 in the linked server settings? You said that it was set to 0.

Comment: no effect. 300 would mean 5 minutes (300 seconds). 0 means no timeout (timeout disabled).

Comment: Yes, you are correct right. I set the stored procedure wait time. Now also got the timeout error. I am researching how to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi@saso, My stored procedure will execute for 12 minutes. When I set "remote query timeout" to 900. It successfully returned the result! I've updated my answer.

Comment: In other word. The set value should be a bit larger than the actual execution time. If the values are the same, the timeout error will still be reported.

Comment: Hi Joseph. Thank you. The "Remote Timeout Error" setting is very misleading. Based on the documentation one would expect that setting the value to 0 (disabling it) means that the query is allowed to run until it is completed. This is not the case - setting the value to 0 means that the server-wide timeout setting is applied - and it seems that it is not possible to change this server-wide setting on Azure SQL servers.  The solution is to set this value on the linked server settings to a value that is higher that query execution time. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: just on side note: there is no reason to create 2 linked servers. 1 is enough.